# How to check or throw user defined exception for value which is not there in ENUM , Let say I passes Metadata= "DF" from postman

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

```
public enum Metadata{
    AC, CD;
}
```

I am getting json parser error when passing value which is not there in enum..and that error is very lengthy and not readable to user ..instead I should get a proper readable message but I dont know how to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

> instead I should get a proper readable message

Then you need to implement a method that would validate the input and in the case if provided *enum-name* doesn't exist it would throw an exception with a suitable message.

That's how it might look like:

```
public enum Metadata{
    AC, CD;
    
    public static Metadata get(String name) {
        if (!isValid(name)) throw new MyExceptoin("message");

        return valueOf(name);
    }
    
    public static boolean isValid(String name) {
        
        return Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(name));
    }
}
```

It would be more cleaner approach than catching an `IllegalArgumentException` (because it's a runtime exception)  that can be thrown `valueOf()`, and then throwing a desired exception from the `catch` block. And you can't gain a significant performance advantage with this approach since there will be only a few enum-members.

*Just for illustrative purposes, that's how an exception can be caught and rethrowing:*

```
public static Metadata get(String name) {
    try {
        return valueOf(name);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new MyExceptoin("message");
    }
}
```

Comment: When I throw my custum exception inside enum Metadata so it is going to httpMessageNotReadableException instead of my custom @ExceptionHandler method .. what changes shall I make so that flow goes to my handler